# set string to calendar type

Tags: java, string, calendar

I have a code like

```
Customer_Todo_Master customerTodo=new Customer_Todo_Master();
customerTodo.setCALCDATE(String type);
```

here `setCALCDATE` is a calendar type. How can i set a string to this `setCALCDATE()`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

using [**SimpleDateFormat**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) class:

```
String str="your string rep of cal"; 
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.setTime(new SimpleDateFormat("your date format").parse(str));
customerTodo.setCALCDATE(cal);
```